# Google Apps Script: Is a date part with a range

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I would like to determine what season a date falls between.  The date is in a cell and is not related to the current date.

I have gotten this far:

```
var myDate=myForm.getRange("C4").getValue();

if (Utilities.formatDate(myDate, "GMT", 'MM/dd')>'12/21' && Utilities.formatDate(myDate, "GMT", 'MM/dd')<'3/20'){
  ui.alert("Winter")
}
```

I would repeat this obviously for other seasons.

My expectation is that 1/13/2023 evaluates to 1/13 by `(Utilities.formatDate(myDate, "GMT", 'MM/dd')` and falls with the range.

That is not happening

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Utilites.formatDate() does not return dates it returns strings.  The only way to compare data numerically is by using valueOf() or gettime() methods

Comment: Can I do a valueof on part of a date?  I dont care about the year.  Just need to the 1/25 falls between 12/21 and 3/20

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of comparing today's date with the season.

```
function getSeason() {
  try {
    // per Farmers Almanac
    let season = ["Winter","Spring","Summer","Fall"];
    let seasons = [["12/21/2021","3/20/2022","6/21/2022","9/22/2022","12/21/2022","3/20/2023"],
                   ["12/21/2022","3/20/2023","6/21/2023","9/23/2023","12/21/2023","3/20/2024"],
                   ["12/21/2023","3/19/2024","6/20/2024","9/22/2024","12/21/2024","3/20/2025"],
                   ["12/21/2024","3/20/2025","6/20/2025","9/22/2025","12/21/2025","3/20/2026"],
                   ["12/21/2025","3/20/2026","6/21/2026","9/22/2026","12/21/2026","3/20/2027"]];
    let today = new Date();
    let year = today.getFullYear()-2022;
    today = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate());
    let found = seasons[year].findIndex( (date,index) => {
        return today >= new Date(date) && today < new Date(seasons[year][index+1]);
      }
    );
    console.log(today);
    console.log(season[found])
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

12:20:50 PM Notice  Execution started
12:20:50 PM Info    Mon Sep 12 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
12:20:50 PM Info    Summer
12:20:50 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- [Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Season of the year:

```
function seasonOfTheYear(date) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ds = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const sObj = { pA: [] };
  ds.forEach(s => {
    sObj[new Date(s[1]).valueOf()] = { start: new Date(s[1]), season: s[0] };
    sObj.pA.push(new Date(s[1]).valueOf());
  });
  let dv = new Date(date).valueOf();
  let ssn = sObj.pA.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (dv >= c && dv < sObj.pA[(i + 1) % sObj.pA.length]) {
      a["season"] = sObj[c].season;
    }
    return a;
  }, {season:''}).season;
  Logger.log(ssn);
}
```

I got this data from timeandate.com and put it into Sheet0

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| SPRING | Tuesday, March 1 |
| SUMMER | Wednesday, June 1 |
| FALL | Thursday, September 1 |
| WINTER | Thursday, December 1 |

Comment: I modified this a bit and am close.  I cant figure out where, but if I use a date that is too far in the past, the season is not returned.  It is blank.  What would cause that?

Comment: Yeah cause I'm running off of current year data.

Comment: What would I change to make it work for past years?

Comment: Provide historical data.  I'm just check to see what date range the date is in.  If you want to provide more historical data you could add the year to SPRING,SUMMER,FALL,WINTER and do pretty much the same thing.  Get me the data I will do it for you.  Post the data in a table so I can copy it.